# How to retrieve the data using ASP.NET ObjectDataSource based on the QueryString?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repository-pattern, objectdatasource

I am new ASP.NET Web Forms developer and I am trying to develop n-layered application using ObjectDataSource with the Repository Pattern. So far, I am doing well but I am struggling with retrieving the data in one of pages based on the value of the QueryString.

I have the following database schema:

```
Product Table: Id, Title, CategoryId
Category Table: Id, Title
```

The user has to access the page that lists all the categories. Then, when he selects one of the categories, he will be redirected to another page that lists the products based on the selected category. I am still struggling with this and I couldn't find how to fix it.

ASP.NET Code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="productList" runat="server"
                            DataSourceID="odsProduct" DataKeyNames="Id">
                            <LayoutTemplate>
                                <ul class="cbp-ig-grid">
                                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                </ul>
                            </LayoutTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li class=" animated7">
                                    <a href="ProductDetails.aspx?productID=<%#Eval("Id") %>">
                                        <img src="../Assets/upload/Products/<%#Eval("ImagePath") %>" width="350" height="190">
                                        <h3 class="cbp-ig-title"><%#Eval("Name") %></h3>
                                        <span class="cbp-ig-category"><%#Eval("Description") %></span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                <span>No data was returned.</span>
                            </EmptyDataTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
                        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsProduct" runat="server"
                            TypeName="ThinkSafetyFirst_DatabaseFirst.BLL.ProductBL"
                            DataObjectTypeName="ThinkSafetyFirst_DatabaseFirst.DAL.Product"
                            SelectMethod="GetProducts">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="categoryId" Name="CategoryId " />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Here's the C# code for the ProductRepository class:

```
public class ProductRepository : IDisposable, IProductRepository
    {
        private readonly TestContext dbContext = new TestContext();

        public IEnumerable<TTSF_Product> GetProducts()
        {
            return dbContext.TTSF_Product.Include("TTSF_Category").ToList();
        }


        public TTSF_Product GetProduct(int id)
        {
            TTSF_Product proObj = dbContext.TTSF_Product.Find(id);
            return proObj;
        }
}
```

**Could you please tell me why I am still getting the following error?**

[image]

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Are you suppose to use productID instead of categoryID as the query string? From the looks of your href value, you're using productID.

Answer (score 2):

In the `ObjectDataSource` you are defining your `SelectMethod` as `GetProducts` but the method `GetProducts` in your repository does not have a parameter called `CategoryId`

You should add an overload for `GetProducts` method that takes `CategoryId` as parameter.

Comment: So the `Include("TTSF_Category")` will not do anything for such a case like this?

Comment: Yep, the thing is that you're calling a method with a parameter which does not exists in your repository object

Comment: thanks for your clarification. So there is no feature of EntityFramework which enables me to retrieve a list of products based on the value of the foreign key which is the Category ID? Also, I would appreciate if you could provide me with a code snippet for the method that will enable me to retrieve the data based on the value of the QueryString

Comment: Do you mean to load i.e.: Products where the CategoryID is 2?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: Then you would have to create a Linq query to bring products where their CategoryId is x based on the parameter. What you did with the Include is called Eager loading and it works for including related entities as part of the query. Check this out

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/eager-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx